# Covid 19 regionalized historical hospitalization data for european countries

Tags: historical, covid19

I am looking for the regionalized historical covid 19 data for western european countries, especially the number of hospitalization.

By regionalized, I mean for each subdivision of a given country (lander for germany for example).

By historical, I mean data for, ideally, every day since last march.

By western european I mean Germany, Italy, Switzerland, Spain and Portugal mainly.

France already have precise historical data per departements: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/63352e38-d353-4b54-bfd1-f1b3ee1cabd7 (from https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/donnees-relatives-aux-resultats-des-tests-virologiques-covid-19/). I would like the equivalent for the aforementioned countries.

Comment: there are various (many) resources on this question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16185/1511

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COVID19 - Coronavirus case data (country summary data)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16185/covid19-coronavirus-case-data-country-summary-data)

Comment: @Pluviophile Germany does not have historical data on hospitalization on lander or region in the provided answer (as far as I can tell). Switzerland is a mess as apparently every canton has a different reporting system. Italy is fine and I have yet to evaluate Spain.

Comment: I think for Austrian hospitalizations, you can use this page/scraper https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/18094/1511

Comment: Great dataset from @philshem for switzerland: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/18498/18246

Comment: @Pluviophile for spain the data here: https://rubenfcasal.github.io/COVID-19/ has the number of hospitalization per provinces however it seems that their definition of hospitalization is strange. It is the number of admission per day, not the number of occupied bed. So can't use that to compare with other countries.

Answer (score 2):

Switzerland's COVID hospitalizations are available from the federal government:

https://www.covid19.admin.ch/en/epidemiologic/hosp

In the footer of the page, you'll see download links for raw data (csv or json)

[image: csv and json downloads]

The hospitalizations are available across 4 files, depending on which dimensions you'd like to see the data (age, gender, etc). If you browse the data on the website [above](https://www.covid19.admin.ch/en/epidemiologic/hosp), the naming of fields will be more clear.

[image: csv examples of swiss covid hospitalization data]

---

The URLs of the zipped json and csv archives have unique hashes when they are updated. But with some *curl-magic* you can fetch the newest version:

```
curl -o covid19-data.zip https://www.covid19.admin.ch` \
  curl -s https://www.covid19.admin.ch/en/ \
    | grep -o '"[^"]*sources-json.zip"' \
    | cut -d '"' -f 2`
```

source: https://gist.github.com/rkaravia/36e461305bed8cf3fb62be4ea61c3325

Comment: BTW - with CH and all its regions, you also get [FL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liechtenstein) ;)

Comment: Perfect data source. Well organized, clear. Thumb ups to the swisses!

Answer (score 0):

For some countries you've already got links in comments, so here is an answer for Germany.

For Germany, you can get visualization on County-Level from the [Risklayer](http://www.risklayer-explorer.com/event/100/detail) website, which is maintained by CEDIM GmbH, a spin-off from KIT, a large, publicly-funded research institute.

If you scroll down, or search for "Crowdsourcing", on that page,  you'll find a link to a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wg-s4_Lz2Stil6spQEYFdZaBEp8nWW26gVyfHqvcl8s/edit#gid=1167076856) that relies on, well, crowdsourced data.
(At the time I am writing this, 28 people are accessing that document).

Note that this Google sheet has many subsheets. One of them is "Länder" and it contains, for instance, the number of intensive-care units occupied. The number of hospitalizations is probably correlated, but difficult to measure.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken these are not historical data. They are the current status of things. The panel "curve" have historical data but they are not split on lander. I don't speak german so I may have missed something.

Comment: I simply assumed that the historial data is also in the Google Sheet. Both countrywide newspapers ["Tagesspiegel"](https://interaktiv.tagesspiegel.de/lab/karte-sars-cov-2-in-deutschland-landkreise/) and ["Berliner Morgenpost"](https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/corona-virus-karte-infektionen-deutschland-weltweit/) use these data in their respective interactive visualisations. At least they say so in their sources sections ("Quellen").

Comment: Maybe ask the Risklayer people directly? There are "Get in touch" links in the page footer.